# how to animate elements of web page using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

For example, if you want programmatically to define animated movement of some element(s) in the web page. In javascript this can be done as this link describes: [How TO - JavaScript HTML Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp). But in Node.js, how this can be accomplished ?

EDIT: If it can't be accomplished using Node.js, is there a way -for example- to call java script code from the Node.js code to manage the interface of the web page ?

EDIT: Never mind about the last edit, I will do it in the ordinary way.

Comment: Node.js runs on the serverside, it doesn't really animate anything

Comment: Node.js is server side, it has nothing to do with client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't. Nodejs is javascript on the server side, not client side.